# How to set input for proper fit with lstm?

Tags: deep-learning, lstm

My input training and test dataset is the following size:

```
print(trainX.shape):(53394, 3)
print(testX.shape):(17799, 3)
print(trainY.shape):(53394,)
print(testY.shape):(17799,)
```

I reshaped it as follows:

```
trainX.shape:(1, 53394, 3)
testX.shape: (1, 17799, 3)
trainY.shape: (1, 53394)
testY.shape: (1, 17799)
```

Now, I pass it as the input layer of a LSTM:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(66, input_shape=(len(trainX),3)))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(trainX, trainY, epochs=100,batch_size=1, verbose=2)
```

I am getting the error:

```
Error Message: 
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected lstm_6_input to have shape (1, 3) but got array with shape (53394, 3)
```

Please help me to fit my data properly into a LSTM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be structuring your data as a tuple: Number of samples, timesteps, features. In your case number of samples is 53394, timesteps is 1 and number of features is 3. So the input shape will be (53394, 1, 3). 
You can use this snippet of code for the tranformation:

```
trainX = trainX.reshape((trainX.shape[0], 1, 3))
```

And set the argument input_shape  as below:

```
input_shape = (trainX.shape[1], trainX.shape[2])
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you..its working. I am not clear about the batch size? like in total dataset has more than 7000 entries. So should i set batch size as one? If i want to add more layer for the improvement.. how can i do that? Basiclly i am trying to predict y using x1,x2 and x3

Comment: Batch size is a hyper parameter. It is the number of samples processed (forward and backward pass) by the network in one iteration. After that  network weights are updated. So a batch size of 1 means network weights are updated after one sample is processed. You should tune it after tuning other hyperparameters. You should not just set it to 1.

Comment: You can add more layers but most of the problems are handled by one hidden layer. You need to set the argument return_sequences = True in the first hidden layer to add another hidden layer. Thanks for accepting the answer!

Comment: I am able to fit the model. But i am not able to do predictions with it. Basically what i am doing is i am using values of X1,X2 and X3 nd trying to predict value of Y1.

Comment: # make predictions
trainPredict = model.predict(trainX)
testPredict = model.predict(testX)
# calculate root mean squared error
trainScore = math.sqrt(mean_squared_error(trainY[0], trainPredict[:,0]))
print('Train Score: %.2f RMSE' % (trainScore))
testScore = math.sqrt(mean_squared_error(testY[0], testPredict[:,0]))
print('Test Score: %.2f RMSE' % (testScore))

Comment: What i am getting is same value in trainPredict and testpredict. i dont know why even i am using different sets for training. and then i am getting MSE as zero. please suggest how to predict and calculate correct MSE.

Comment: Please post this as a separate question. Its difficult to find out what exactly is your code doing.