# Why the RNN has input shape error?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, keras, rnn

My `x_train` shape is (798,3) and `y_train` input shape is (798, 1). I am creating a RNN like this

```
def create_rnn_model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(SimpleRNN(20,return_sequences=False,stateful=stateful,activation='relu',batch_input_shape=(1,3,1)))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    adam = optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001)
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=adam, metrics=[root_mean_squared_error])

    return model
```

But this returns the error

> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected simple_rnn_1_input to
>   have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (798, 3)

My batch size =1 and my timestep is 3 and `dat_dim=1` .Then where am I doing it wrong?
Any help is appreciated.

> EDIT

I changed my x_train to shape (798,3,1) and y_train shape to (798,) and ran the model but it threw an error

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected activation_1 to have shape (20,) but got array with shape (1,)
```

But I can run the model with 1 unit. How do I specify the model to run with 20 units instead of one.

Comment: We don't even know what library you are using (and I assume this is python). I think you should provide a working code sample, and ask on stackoverflow (this is a programming question obviously).

Comment: Rather than a programming question my real question is whether am I correct feeding the input or how wrong  I am from the model perspective

Comment: possible duplicate:-https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/32858/how-to-set-input-for-proper-fit-with-lstm/32874#32874

Answer (score 1):

First for RNN part, you should consider to read documentation about **input_shape** and **batch_input_shape**.

Then your Activation layer seems to be useless because you already apply relu activation in RNN layer.

Finally, your network returns output's shape of **(20,)** (RNN return **(20,)** and activation don't change shape) and you compare this with `y_train` with shape of **(1,)**. Shapes dismatch so it return this error

**EDIT**: You can print model.summary() to monitor input/output 's shape

Answer (score 0):

So from research I found out that for a RNN te input has to be in 3D format so I need to reshape by 2D data to 3D data . Then you need to specify the batch size,timestep and data_dim of your data .Hope it helps anyone .